# Facebook mobile ads for installs of iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, deep-linking, facebook-ads-api

I want to track installs of my iOS app associated with a Facebook ad. I'm having trouble implementing the exclusion of users part. On the docs I see the following: "Provide a deep link for your app when creating an ad under "App Exclusion URL"". But I'm not really sure what kind of deeplink do I need and I don't even see the "App Exclusion URL" option when creating the ad. Any help would much appreciated! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This would the URL scheme you have defined in your app which can be used to open your app.

See the [introduction to URL Schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html) in the Apple Developer documentation.